# saving a model after updating enum field is not success

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have three model, Game, Team, and Player. Player belongs to Team and Team belongs to Game. There is no direct relation between Game and Player. Player has a method like:

```
  def game
    @game || team.game
  end
```

And Game has a enum field name "field".

```
class Game < ApplicationRecord
  enum field: { nothing: 0, metal: 1, tree: 2, water: 3, fire: 4, earth: 5 }
```

Player has a method summon, it should change Game's field:

```
  def summon( value )
    game.field = value.to_sym
    game.save!
    save!
  end
```

I checked with byebug. Game's "field" is the value after the assigning. But "field" become nil after save! What happened? Is my game method inside Player would reload @game somewhere?

Comment: Just a side note, look into making the relation "Player has many Games through team".

Comment: Just found my mistake. I change migration but do rake db:reset without redoing db:migrate. The schema.rb didn't change at all.

Comment: In your `#summon` method, you could also do `game.send("#{value.to_sym}!")` to reduce the lines in the method to one.